# Insert HTML table to Notepad (txt file)

Tags: php

I have a requirement where in I want to export the nicely formatted HTML table to 'NOTEPAD'. When exporting to MS WORD document, it takes care of all the formatting and gives a clean output just as seen on the browser, but in Notepad, when exported, all the HTML tags get added and kills the formatting. Is there any built in PHP function that retains the HTML table format even in Notepad?

Comment: Notepad can't display other than text, so you just can use characters like `═║╔╚╠` to create your borders

Comment: Okay... I don't need the pipes and special characters, just new lines and tabs.

Comment: This can be easily done in Word by just copy pasting the table from your browser into Word. But for notepad I am not sure.

Comment: maybe interesting? [HTML table to “graphical text” for code comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848786/html-table-to-graphical-text-for-code-comments)

Comment: The thing was, I wanted to export the HTML table to a notepad (txt file). Did formatting by replacing the </tr> tag with the \r\n and </td> with required number of spaces with the help of str_replace PHP function and then exported to txt file. Keeping my fingers crossed as I hope this shall work on different OS specially must work on Mac machines  :P

Comment: Thanks Ryan, P.S : Didn't need the borders though ;)